# Windows installer fails after deleting Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, boot, crash, bootloader, windows-installation

I'd need help with the following problem. I've built a new PC recently and decided to install Ubuntu on it, that was the first and only OS on the system. a few weeks later I changed my mind about Linux and tried to install windows 7 instead. Regardless of the source of the installer (eg CD or USB) windows just won't start to install. It starts copying files but before the installer would start the system simply restarts.

Now it can't be a hardware issue since Ubuntu works fine, and Linux installer starts just fine. I have tried to swap out the ssd with another, tried formatting and partitioning; I even tried to pull out the RAM and reset CMOS, nothing works.

Can anybody here provide some assistance, please?

At this stage, I just want to install windows nice and clean.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

May be thermal throttling. If you are getting BSOD may be UEFI or Legacy BIOS setting need to be changed. Try installing Windows 10.

Comment: Yh that did do the trick. Win 10 installed without a hitch. Turned out my MOBO did not support win 7 anymore....